# HTTP queries in C++ for Mac

Tags: c++, http, macos

I am porting a Windows C++ program that uses winhttp.h for HTTP POST and GET.
Please give suggestions on what I can use in C++ for Mac instead of winhttp.h.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Cocoa? You can use [NSUrlConnection class][1].

Otherwise, you can use a portable HTTP client in C or C++ such as [CURL/LIBCURL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/curl/).

[1]: http://mywebsite.com/page.php?order=Bananas DESC

Comment: No, I am not using Cocoa, I am using C++

Comment: Thanks, this Libcurl worked. Took me a while because it was my first time but yes, it is absolutely fine.

Comment: Hi Tan - I also need to port some simple HTTP code from Windows to Macintosh. It's a Legacy project on the Mac so I'm stuck with OS 10.4 (Tiger). I just need a simple open HTTP session and GET a page. From your experience, does it seem like I could include the CURL source and get this functionality ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use boost::asio? Simple to use and well designed C++ API for IP. Includes some samples for HTTP GET etc.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: How do you come up with 40 MB? I built a Windows DLL using boost::asio binding the boost libs statically into it. The Size of the dll is 628kb.